# Core-Plot: maintain zoomed-in range on reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

My `CPTScatterPlot` allows pinching to zoom-in to see more detailed data, as well as some parameters that can be changed. Whenever the parameters are changed, I recalculate the data points, followed by `reloadData`. However, that again shows the whole data range, instead of keeping the zoomed-in range.

**EDIT**: What I have tried so far:

```
-(CPTPlotRange *)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPTPlotRange *)newRange forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate
{
    CPTPlotRange *updatedRange = nil;

    switch ( coordinate )
    {
        case CPTCoordinateX:
            if ([newRange isEqualToRange: ((CPTXYPlotSpace *)space).globalXRange]) {
                updatedRange = ((CPTXYPlotSpace *)space).xRange;
            }
            else {
                updatedRange = newRange;
            }
        break;

    case CPTCoordinateY:
    case CPTCoordinateZ:
    case CPTCoordinateNone:
        break;
    }

    return updatedRange;
}
```

I have a hunch I need to do this in this delegate method, but I have not yet been able to figure out how.

Is there a way to maintain the zoomed-in range whenever `reloadData` is called?

**EDIT 2**: Solved by adding a `dataIsLoaded` flag so that I only set `xRange` initially, but not on every re-calculation. The `delegate` method above is not related to the problem.

Comment: Reloading the plot data is independent of the plot space. Do you call `-scaleToFitPlots:` or make similar plot space calculations after loading the new plot data?

Comment: No to both questions. Am I on the right track in using willChangePlotRangeTo: ?

Comment: Just changing the plot data has no effect on the plot ranges in the plot space. Can you post the code that loads the new data? Also, what is this delegate method supposed to do? I doubt that the new range will ever be exactly equal to the global range.

Comment: Ok, I went back to my code and saw that I *do* set the plotRanges. I initially call it from `viewDidLoad`, but of course there is no data at that point. So I was calling it as well whenever the dataSource is (re)calculated. I need to refactor that. Just that I understand correctly: `globalXRange` is the total range of all datapoints, and `xRange` is the visible range? I that case I only need to change `globalXRange` based on the new datapoints, and leave the `xRange` alone, correct?

Comment: The global range sets limits on the plot range. When the global range is set, on any change to the plot range, the new range is compared to the global range and moved and/or resized to fit within the global range as needed.